# How can I fix the login issue which is not working after CSRF is enabed with Spring Boot and Spring Security?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-security, csrf

I have a [Spring Boot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spring_Framework#Spring_Boot) application. I am using Spring Security. When I tried to enable to CSRF, the login functionality failed. It was working before enabling spring security. Please find the attachment and below steps which I did to enable CSRF. How can I fix this issue?

**Security configuration**

```
http
    .authorizeRequests()
    .antMatchers("/ui/static/assets/**").permitAll()
     .antMatchers("/register","/forgotPassword").permitAll()
    .anyRequest().authenticated()
    .and()
    .formLogin()
    .loginPage("/login")
    .permitAll()
    .defaultSuccessUrl("/addDocument")
    .failureHandler(customAuthenticationFailureHandler)
    .and().exceptionHandling().accessDeniedPage("/Access_Denied")
    .and().logout().permitAll().invalidateHttpSession(true);
```

**login.jsp**

```
<form action="${pageContext.servletContext.contextPath}/login" class="form-horizontal" method="post" id="formLogin" data-parsley-validate="">
    <sec:csrfInput />
    <input class="form-control input-lg" type="email" name="username" id="username"  placeholder="Enter your email" data-parsley-required="true">
    <input class="form-control input-lg" type="password" id="pwd" name="password" placeholder="Enter your password" data-parsley-required="true">
    <button class="btn w-lg btn-rounded btn-lg btn-primary waves-effect waves-light" id="signInBtn" type="submit" value="Next" >Sign In
</form>
```

**addDocument.jsp**

```
<form:form method="POST" action="${pageContext.servletContext.contextPath}/submitDocument" id="fileUploadForm" enctype="multipart/form-data" modelAttribute="documentSignature">
    <form:hidden path="rewrite" value="true" />
    <sec:csrfInput/>

    <div class="form-group row">
        <label class="control-label col-md-3">Upload Document <span class="text-danger">*</span></label>
        <div class="controls col-md-9">
            <div class="form-group">
                  <input type="file" class="filestyle" id="fileUpload" name="file" data-buttonname="btn-primary" data-iconname="fa fa-upload">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group row">
         <label class="col-lg-12 control-label ">(*) Mandatory</label>
    </div>

    <div class="actions clearfix">
        <!-- <input class="btn btn-primary customButton" id="btnAddDocument" type="submit" value="Next" >
        <i class="fas fa-spinner fa-spin" id="loadingBtn" style="display:none;"></i>     -->
        <button class="btn customButton btn-primary waves-effect waves-light" id="btnAddDocument" type="submit" value="Next">Next
        <i class="fas fa-spinner fa-spin" id="loadingBtn" style="display:none;"></i></button>
    </div>
</form:form>
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: what do you mean by .antMatchers("**/login").authenticated() ?? 
login should be authenticated ?

Comment: Thank you so much for your update. Highly appreciate it :) . I fixed the login page but then after login i am unable to go to addDocument Page. I have permitted this page to render too. Not sure about the issue . it is throwing 404 error after i login. It enters addDocument method in controller but the JSP is not being rendered. Can you please suggest what to do ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you would define your custom login page then:
In `loginPage("/showLoginPage")` you should pass url for mapping to your controller. And you need to add `loginProcessingUrl("/authenticate")` for submit request. (you could see [javadoc about **FormLoginConfigurer.loginPage()**](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/api/org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/configurers/FormLoginConfigurer.html#loginPage-java.lang.String-))
Example: your possible
**login controller**

```
   @Controller
    public class LoginController {

        @GetMapping("/showLoginPage")
        public String showLoginPage() {
            return "login";  // your login jsp page
        }
    }
```

**In SecurityConfuration**

```
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
http. 
...
.loginPage("/showLoginPage")
.loginProcessingUrl("/authenticate")
```

**In JSP page login.jsp:**

```
 <form:form action="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/authenticate" method="post">   
    <%-- authenticate=loginProcessingUrl-->
    ...  
</form:form>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your update. Highly appreciate it :) . I fixed the login page but then after login i am unable to go to addDocument Page. I have permitted this page to render in Security Config. Not sure about the issue . it is throwing 404 error after i login. It enters addDocument method in controller but the JSP is not being rendered. Can you please suggest what to do ?

Comment: Did you debug your controller method that is mapped to "/submitDocument". Does this method call? Could you share your code for controller?

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the update. The request is not hitting /submitDocument method. This method is not getting called :( ! This is the method signature   "  @PostMapping("/submitDocument")
    public ModelAndView submitDocument(@ModelAttribute("DocumentSignature") DocumentSignature documentSignature,
      @Nullable @RequestParam("file") MultipartFile content,
            @RequestParam(value = "url", required = false) String url,
            @RequestParam("rewrite") Boolean rewrite,
      Principal user,Authentication authentication,HttpServletRequest request){  "

Answer (score 1):

If `CSRF` is enabled, you have to include a `_csrf`.token in the page you want to login or logout.In your `login.jsp` I do not see that being included which might be causing the issue.

From the official documentation, the following are the two ways to add the CSRF header:

In your JSP code, you can include it in your form like:

> If you are using Spring MVC form:form tag, the CsrfToken is
> automatically included for you using the
> CsrfRequestDataValueProcessor.

```
<c:url var="logoutUrl" value="/logout"/>
<form action="${logoutUrl}"
    method="post">
  <input type="submit"
    value="Log out" />
  <input type="hidden"
    name="${_csrf.parameterName}"
    value="${_csrf.token}"/>
</form
```

Or if you prefer to use Ajax for the request then you can add the CSRF headers to the Ajax request manually. In that case, you can add the CSRF token as meta tags in the HTML and use jQuery or JavaScript to get the toke from html to be added in the Ajax request.

```
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="_csrf" content="${_csrf.token}"/>
    <!-- default header name is X-CSRF-TOKEN -->
    <meta name="_csrf_header" content="${_csrf.headerName}"/>
    ...
  </head>


$(function () {
    var token = $("meta[name='_csrf']").attr("content");
    var header = $("meta[name='_csrf_header']").attr("content");
    $(document).ajaxSend(function(e, xhr, options) {
        xhr.setRequestHeader(header, token);
    });
});
```

The code above is taken from [the official documentation](https://spring.io/blog/2013/08/21/spring-security-3-2-0-rc1-highlights-csrf-protection/#use-proper-http-verbs).

Comment: Thank you for the update. The tag <sec:csrfInput /> is rendered with csrf token and parameter name in jsp.  I fixed the login page but then after login i am unable to go to addDocument Page. I have permitted this page to render in Security Config. Not sure about the issue . it is throwing 404 error after i login. It enters addDocument method in controller but the JSP is not being rendered. Can you please suggest what to do ?

Comment: Oh alright, how did you fix the login page then ? Since you have enabled csrf it should be added to every page.Can you provide the error and the html for the page addDocument and the controller so that we may have a clarity on the issue.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the update. I fixed the login page by providing proper paths for the resources in security config. I was able to login. After login, I was able to go to the login success url which is addDocument. Now, When i try to upload the document and click on next, the post /submitDocument is not working. It display 404 Error. Please find the attached screenshots.  I have updated my code above. csrf is generated in addDocument in the above screenshot. There is no error from controller side. Can you please let me know what could be the issue ?

Comment: The post requests also requires csrf header and token to be successful. Can you check when you submit the form the csrf is in the request

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the update. The request is not hitting /submitDocument method :( ! Do you have any idea what could be the issue ? This is the method signature   "  @PostMapping("/submitDocument")
    public ModelAndView submitDocument(@ModelAttribute("DocumentSignature") DocumentSignature documentSignature,
      @Nullable @RequestParam("file") MultipartFile content,
            @RequestParam(value = "url", required = false) String url,
            @RequestParam("rewrite") Boolean rewrite,
      Principal user,Authentication authentication,HttpServletRequest request){  "

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the update. I added extra form parameter but there is no luck. I have attached the request and response headers. Proper request is not being sent. Can you please have a look ?

Comment: I think your issue occur because of the multipart form data, there is a section on using multipart/form-data with csrf .Please check the official doc to verify if you have missed something : https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/5.0.x/reference/html/csrf.html#csrf-include-csrf-token-in-action

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the update. It worked. Highly appreciated. I have 2 more concerns. Can you please address them ? When i try to login, the login is successful but the HTTP status code is 302. Is it the correct behavior ? Also, when i click on logout, i m using default logout feature of spring security. But logout is not working because of CSRF. It is showing 404 error. How can i fix this ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/195103/discussion-between-ananthapadmanabhan-and-nithin).